# nodejs, run test automatically when files change

Tags: testing, node.js, tdd

Is there a way to automatically run tests, when a file in the app is changed? In rails there is a gem called guard. How can one achieve the same in nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> touch /tmp/nt; while [ true ]; do if [ `find . -newer /tmp/nt -type f
>   | grep -v app/cache | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then phpunit; touch /tmp/nt; fi;
>   sleep 5; done

I'm using it to autostart phpunit. Replace phpunit with the command to run tests
replace `sleep 5` with `sleep 1` if you wish to check every second (depends on the size of your files)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this would work for tests, but Nodemon (https://github.com/remy/nodemon) looks like what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it uses a polling mechanism - guard is much more efficient using each OS' notification mechanism.

Comment: Even works in Windows/Python:  nodemon --exec "python tests/test_api.py" --watch ./ --ext py

Answer (score 1):

Install [Jasmine](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) and run

```
    jasmine-node <dir> --autotest
```